# Can a neural network predict a timeseries based on other timeseries?

Tags: keras, neural-network, time-series, conv-neural-network

I want to predict a time series X1 of n points based on two different time series X2 and X3, also of n points each. Those time series interact, so I was hoping to use similar methods as with combining images to produce another image.

So far I have successfully implemented an autoencoder to learn and return all time series (X1, X2, X3). When I tried to set up a neural network to use X2 and X3 only to predict X1 (of 3000 units) the model doesn't compile and I am getting an error:

```
Error when checking target: expected sequential_9 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (61, 3000, 1, 1)
```

In different combinations it breaks at `flatten_x` or `dense_x`. 
**It works if my output is of only one unit and not 3000.**

The network I tried would have the following layers:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_8 (InputLayer)         (None, 3000, 2, 1)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 3000, 2, 32)       96        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling2 (None, 1500, 2, 32)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_7 (Flatten)          (None, 96000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 3000, 1, 32)
```

Here is the code that I'm using to create the net:

```
network = Sequential((
    Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(1,2), activation='relu', input_shape=(x, y, inChannel)),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 1)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(3000, activation='relu'),
))
network.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = RMSprop())
```

The input has shape (61, 3000, 2, 1).

**Should I specify the expected inputs/outputs somewhere and I'm not doing that? Make some data transformations on the way? Maybe use a different architecture?**

Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The network you've coded does not have the architecture you intended**

If you print out

```
network.summary()
```

you get

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 3000, 1, 32)       96        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling2 (None, 1500, 1, 32)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 48000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 3000)              144003000 
=================================================================
Total params: 144,003,096
Trainable params: 144,003,096
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

So, you have to change your architecture to get the desired output shape.